# Use particular formula based on referenced value

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula

I am working on creating a price list that uses calculated values to determine the price based on cost of good sold, area, and a few other things for some items.

There are different formulas used depending on the item type.

For example, prints would be calculated with an AREA multiplier type using the equation [@Multiplier]*[@Area]  (referencing formatted table values, but they could also be typical references (f2*g2 for example)

So my question is, how could I set it so that a lookup of the multiplier type will reference a table that has the formula needed for that calculation.

I figured something like vlookup, but that either displays the equation itself, not the result, or doesnt work at all.

Currently, I have a big IF statement that works, but is a pain if I want to change the formula.

```
=MROUND(IF([@Mtype]='Multipliers 2'!$V$4,'Multipliers2'!W4,IF([@Mtype]='Multipliers 2'!$V$3,[@Multiplier]*[@Area]+40,IF([@Mtype]='Multipliers 2'!$V$5,2*[@[Cost of Goods]]+[@Multiplier], IF([@Mtype]='Multipliers 2'!$V$6,[@Area]*[@[Cost of Goods]]*[@Multiplier],[@Multiplier])))),0.5)
```

To Clarify, each product will have a multiplier type, along with data associated with the product that will be used for calculations:

So if I mark a product to use calculation A, the program should go look in a formula table, figure out what Calculation A is and then use those values to determine the result.  If Calculation A = (Multiplier + 2*cost of goods sold), then it will look up the value in the multiplier column and add it to 2 x COGS.

Calculation B may be Multiplier * COGS and so on.

A problem I had last time I tried this a while ago was that even if I were to get the value to return some sort of result, I couldn't get the reference to change properly to correspond to the required row.

[image: Sample Data]

The data above is a small sample of what I'd be doing. Each product is part of a product type which has multiple variations in size, etc. So each product would reference a multiplier table which is used to calculate the final price, so if I want to change the prices for the entire group, all I'd have to do is change the value in the multiplier table, or the equation, and every corresponding product adjust accordingly.

The mtype would be controlled by the multiplier table. So I would like to set it so that if a particular mtype is used, the final calculation in the Price column will be determined by the formula listed.

Comment: Lookup for the `MATCH` function on Google

Comment: I'll put something together

Comment: I attached a picture with sample data

Comment: Are the ranges `A1:I6` and `C10:F15` excel tables?

Comment: Correct, though in my actual file, they are spread out over several sheets, with lots more data.

Comment: You can only hate this site if you use it incorrectly. you should take the [tour] some times